# In Volumio, how do you rename a multiroom device?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, audio-streaming

I just set up 3 Raspberry Pi Zeros using the normal wifi-based setup and leaving all the defaults. Each pi is working and accessible by going to volumio.local and then switching between them in the Multiroom Devices section. The default names given by the setup process are "VOLUMIO", "VOLUMIO #2", and "VOLUMIO-3". How do I change these so that they better reflect the room they are serving? I checked in the settings menus but couldn't find anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

run the wizard on each one
its ask for Its name
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDBF1.png)